# New Elixir project in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, elixir

I've recently started using Elixir and I'd like to keep my code files in quite decent order. So I installed Elixir plugin for Intellij: https://github.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir, but stuck with trying to start an Elixir project. Could you give me some tips how to make new Elixir project?

Comment: Sounds dumb but drop out to a shell prompt and do "mix new" (minus the double quotes, of course).  Granted it'd be nice to have it in intellij-elixir but Luke's doing his best and he's doing it by himself.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the maintainer of intellij-elixir.  Please file support question as Issues on github: https://github.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir/issues.  In fact, someone already asked a similar question (https://github.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir/issues/77).  In summary, right now you can't create "Elixir Project".  There isn't yet an "Elixir Project" feature/action although you're welcome to open an issue to make that a feature request.  (It's nice if you open it instead of me opening it for you as you'll be subscribed to updates then.)  With the feature set as is, you can create any type of project you like because all that matters is that the file extension is .ex for the Syntax Highlighting, Grammar parsing, Inspections and Quick Fixes to work.  I just create the default Java project when testing intellij-elixir in Intellij or an empty directory or project layout created by `mix new` in Rubymine.  Since two people at least have brought this up I'll add something to README after I'm finished with https://github.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir/issues/59.

Comment: I've opened a feature request issue (https://github.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir/issues/78) for Elixir Project support.  You should Subscribe to notification for the issue if you want to notified when the feature is released